# Issue debugging angular2 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

posted this on github but not sure if thats the right place to post. I've created a project using the latest angular-cli (beta.18). Seems the sourcemaps are incorrect as breakpoints in dev tools dont reflect where they are set:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent extends OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dosomething();
  }

  title = 'app works!';

  dosomething() {
    this.title = "trying to do something";
    this.title = "trying to do something else";
  }
}
```

[image]

anyone else seeing this issue with projects build with angular-cli beta.18?

issue in github: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1519

/Eric

Comment: Is it already using the webpack version? What version of angular are you using?

Comment: angular 2.1.1. The project was created this morning with the angular-cli beta.18. Yes uses webpack, this was working in previous versions of the cli. Everything works fine except debugging as far as i can tell

Comment: Strange. I have beta.16 and it works. Previous versions had issues with the source map and then under node_modules/angular-cli/.../tasks you had a a common file where you had to change from cheap-source-map or sth like that to source map. I looked for the link but couldn't find it. Yet, this was in older versions and should have been fixed. You could try removing angular cli and installing beta.16, I know this is long and painful, but will at least tell you if it is a specific version issue

Comment: Thanks @Meir, ill try rolling back to 17 and see if that helps

Comment: Try 16 first, it works on my machine, and obviously update us, we're curious

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround for me was to update file `node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-development.js` in my project and replace `cheap-module-source-map` to `source-map`. 
Really annoying issue, almost got mad with it :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been resolved in the latest release beta.19-3